# My website form has stopped working since i migrated

Tags: php, email, plesk

I have a basic form on my site with fields like name, email etc. It sends to my email address with theses details normally.

However! I have just got myself a dedicated server with plesk on it.
I have pointed my name servers to my new dedicated server, and have got the site on there live. I have also recreated the email addresses with mailboxes, which all work.

BUT my site now does not want to send emails.

I have tested it again with this basic code without any luck.

```
<?php 
$Name = "Da Duder"; //senders name 
$email = "no-reply@mydomain.co.uk"; //senders e-mail adress 
$recipient = "myemail@gmail.com"; //recipient 
$mail_body = "The text for ddfthe mail..."; //mail body 
$subject = "Subjectdfdfd"; //subject 
$header = "From: ". $Name . " <" . $email . ">\r\n"; //optional headerfields 

mail($recipient, $subject, $mail_body, $header); //mail command :) 
?>
```

I have been reading around about modifying the php.ini file to allow anonymous sending or something which is beyond my knowledge of PHP.

Is there anything i can check?

Comment: what's the mail log say?

Comment: what is the return value of [`mail`](http://php.net/mail)?

Comment: depends, what's your mail server?

Comment: it returns true. if thats what u mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try finding out your email settings, perhaps you don't have a correct servers settings. phpinfo() is a good way to start looking

Comment: SMTP localhost localhost
smtp_port 25 25

Comment: is this the settings i need to look at?

Comment: yeah. these the ones. you need to change them to a working SMTP server. I'm not really familiar with the details, try googleing PHP SMTP server. I found this: http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/Configure_PHP_to_Use_a_Remote_SMTP_Server_for_Sending_Mail.htm

Answer (score 0):

Have you set-up the dedicated server yourself?

Do you have `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE)` and `ini_set('display_errors', 'On')` for testing?

Did you check your junk-mail folder?

Are you sure PHP is not throwing an error? Try this to make sure:

```
if(mail($recipient, $subject, $mail_body, $header)){
    echo "Mail has been sent without errors";
} else {
    echo "Mail has *not* been sent";
}
```

Otherwise ask a system or network adminstrator :-)